# Зависает сайт при открытии baloon

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

Здравствуйте.
Установил на сайт [zakroycredit.ru](https://zakroycredit.ru/) карту по API. 
Отлаживал все в firefox. Все работает красиво и здорово. 
Ничего сложного не делал, просто установил на карте несколько меток, заполнил подсказки и балун для каждой, а также поменял их ширину, чтобы контент полностью в них помещался и отключил скроллинг в десктопной версии сайта и скролинг и драгинг в мобильной версии. 
Код скопипастил из песочницы с примерами.

Когда стал проверять сайт на Crome, карта отображается и работает до тех пор пока не нажмешь на балун. В этот момент весь сайт зависает, перестает листаться, не помогает даже кнопка обновления сайта, а иногда не реагирует даже на закрытие страницы. Аналогичная ситуация в Яндекс-браузере.
Подскажите, что я делаю не так?
Вот ссылка на [код](https://zakroycredit.ru/wp-content/themes/zakroykredit/js/behaviors.js)

Comment: Ошибка воспроизводится (хром, линукс) - нагрузка на проц уходит под 100%.
Попробуй поставить точек остановки в консоли в подозрительных местах скрипта - похоже на бесконечный цикл.

Comment: В коде JS API Карт , который вы предоставили проблемы нет https://jsfiddle.net/cmomLnve/ . Видимо проблема появляется в процессе встраивания.

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с такой же проблемой. Путём отсеивания скриптов и стилей выявил, что ломали работу скриптов стили для картинок. По клику на балун у нас открывалось маленькое окошко с адресами емейлами и тд + логотип, вот выставил этому логотипу(обычный тег img) ширину 100пх и всё как часы заработало, как только ставил width: 100% зависал сайт, и админка сайта почему то тоже, что очень странно. Надеюсь кому то это поможет.